# Event listener is removed on removing the target node?

Tags: javascript, events, listener, addeventlistener

```
link.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
```

adds a listener

The way to remove it is:

```
link.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
```

If I should remove for any reason the link node with:

```
link.remove()
```

How much memory safe is?
I mean, can I just remove the node, and the listener is removed with it?

I cannot find documentation about it.
I need to do it in a game maybe many times.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

> I mean, can I just remove the node, and the listener is removed with
> it?

Yes, when the DOM element is removed, any handler registrations for it are removed as well (since the handler registration is stored with the element). The handler function itself, is not.